# "No module named" Error When Importing Django Models Outside the Django App

Tags: python, django, import

I have a repo containing a Django app, and then some scripts that need to do various things to the database that's behind the app. Ideally, I'd love to use the Django ORM to do edits and updates to this database, since Django leaves me with some pretty ugly MYSQL table names (my_app_sometablename). Doing it through the ORM would also be nice for consistency reasons, and all the other reasons the ORM exists in the first place.

Anyway, I'm having a lot of difficulty importing the Django models properly from outside of the app. I've tried editing my PYTHONPATH, and I've tried importing like 50 different ways, and still no dice. The structure is like:

```
repo/
   __init__.py
   django_app/
      __init__.py
      sub1a/
         __init__.py
         models.py
   scripts/
      __init__.py
      some_script.py
```

I'm trying to do:

```
from django_app.sub1a.models import SomeModel
```

I can actually get that part to work, if I add the path to the repo to my Python path, but then when I try to use what I imported by doing something like:

```
res = SomeModel.objects.filter(**kwargs)
```

I get:

```
  ...
  File "/path/to/.virtualenvs/repo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 64, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name, True)
  File "/path/to/.virtualenvs/analyticsv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 86, in load_app
    app_module = import_module(app_name)
  File "/path/to/.virtualenvs/analyticsv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named sub1a
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I fix it? This is driving me nuts.

Answer (score 3):

You could just do your own django admin commands that performs the tasks you need.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/#howto-custom-management-commands

Comment: Yeah, but some of these scripts really have nothing to do with the app, and there are a lot of them. Forcing all of them to be run through django admin seems messy. We already do some stuff through django admin, but these scripts I'd prefer to keep and run separately.

Comment: @Eli this has nothing to do with the admin site, these are standalone administration scripts that run through `manage.py`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I know. I'd still prefer not to run every single script I need that access the django db through manage.py. I want stuff that's directly related to the app there, and nothing else.

Comment: this might help : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#using-settings-without-setting-django-settings-module